# Trouble setting with git

Tags: git, github, controlled-folder-access

I'm getting this error when trying to set the git init:

$ git init
error: could not lock config file C:/Users/khaled/Desktop/firstTemplete/.git/config: No such file or directory
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'

anyone have any idea ?

Comment: need more explanation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Windows, the problem could occur due to the unauthorized changes for a folder are blocked by the virus and threat protection software.

1. Open your Windows Defender Security Center
2. Go to Home
3. Click and open "Virus and Threat protection"
4. Click and open "Virus and threat Protection Setting"
5. Click and open "Manage Controlled folder access" in "Controlled folder access"option
6. Turn the "Controlled Folder access" OFF

Run "Git init" from cmd.
DONE!

Answer (score 4):

When `git init` is invoked, .git directory is created by GIT and meta information related to the repo including the commits history is created.
This is an issue due to inappropriate write privileges for the current user.

Use `sudo git init`

Or make the base directory writable for the default user

Comment: I suggest checking the official documentation for more insights. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Answer (score 0):

You might not be having sufficient write privileges in the folder. Try using git init with admin access.

1. Open terminal with Admin access.
2. Go th location of folder. 
   cd C:/Users/khaled/Desktop/firstTemplete/
3. Try git init.